How can I implement live changes in celery beat schedule
I want to write a program with celery beat, where I have a view in postgres which should hold the name of a task, cron expression and some other arguments.
I want beat to take those entries from the db, and schedule tasks based on them,
but I also want to update beat if something is changing...
can it be done with the native beat?
if I update the schedule while beat is runnig, will it work and the scheduled tasks would change accordingly?
my idea:
to schedule task to run every X seconds -> query db for changes (I can set "last changed" value)
-> update beat schedule only where there is a change.
is it possible?
What I learned by now:
I looked at other modules like redbeat and django but I wish to save my app as small as possible and preferably independent (I know that I have to have a broker but this would be implemented in AWS SQS)
I learned that I can create a custom scheduler but I think its not recommended (for compatibility reason).
